# Laravel Multiple Middleware cause redirect loop

Tags: php, laravel, middleware

I have a middleware group of auth inside that i want to apply another middleware to one specific route in that view that is if the profile is not completed user cant go to any other route until he complete his profile and submit.

**More Specifically, middle ware is causing loop on redirect because i have 2 middleware.**

i created middleware with laravel php artisan and checking the user if profile is incomplete he should redirect to the profile/edit page but its not even working with just check on incomplete empty companyname.

**Middlware**

```
class incompleteProfile
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if(empty(Auth::user()->details['companyname'])){
            return redirect()->route('profile');
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

**Routes File**

```
Routes
Route::group(['middleware'=>['auth'] ], function(){


// User Profile
Route::get('/profile/edit', 'UserController@profile')->name('profile')->middleware('incompleteProfile');
Route::post('/profile/edit', 'UserController@editProfile')->name('editProfile');
```

Comment: There is a mistake in your if-statement. It should be `if(Auth::user()->details['companyname'] == ""){...}`, without the empty(). If companyname is a direct attribute of user you can write `if(Auth::user()->companyname == ""){...}`

Comment: Also you have to register your middleware in `app/Http/kernel.php` (https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/middleware#registering-middleware)

Comment: my middle ware is register but when condition match it redirects again and again and browser crash then

Comment: if(empty(Auth::user()->details['companyname']) this thing is now working but it redirects again and again and browser gives this error  redirected you too many times.

Comment: Another problem could be, that your edit-page is only reachable via POST. So every redirect goes into Route::get() instead of Route::post(). You should rename your first route (the protected one) to `/profile`. Your edit-route should be `Route::match(['post','get'],'/profile/edit','UserController@editProfile')`. In your controller you have to check if current method is post or get and return a view with the edit-form or handle the form-input.

Comment: what are you trying to stop an 'incomplete profile' user from doing? anything?

Answer (score 3):

If you put that middleware on the `profile` route ... how can they ever get to the `profile` route to get the form to update the profile to add the missing information?

You are saying ... if user details for company name are empty, then redirect to `profile`, but you have that middleware on `profile` ... so its going to forever redirect to `profile` because the middleware is telling it to. Your user can never get to `profile` in this case.

This is the equivalent of assigning the `auth` middleware to the `login` page. The auth middleware checks if the user is currently authenticated. Which means if a user is not authenticated they would never be able to get to `login`, in this scenario, as `login` requires them to be "logged in".

Comment: Nice. (10 more to go...)

Comment: sweet, 10 more what?

Comment: Characters for comment. :D

Comment: heheh :) (7 more to go)

Answer (score 0):

lagbox answer pretty much says the logic of why it doesn't work.
Try it like this.

```
Route::group(['middleware'=>['auth'] ], function(){


// User Profile

    Route::get('/profile/edit', 'UserController@profile')->name('profile');

    Route::group(['middleware'=>['incompleteProfile'] ], function(){
      Route::post('/profile/edit', 'UserController@editProfile')->name('editProfile');
      //ETC
    });

});
```

Comment: unfortunately if they put that middleware on `editProfile` they will never be able to 'update' their profile as they wont get to submit to that route due to the middleware, so same issue, they can just see the form now

Comment: I'm assuming that the profile is edited outside of this routes because as you said it makes no sense to require user to be logged in to login. If user needs to be able to fill the profile the "editProfile" route goes outside the group and all other routes inside the group

Comment: hehe im with you, it is odd, just trying to stay in line with what their example currently has with the limited information as it doesn't quite make sense

Comment: I know its odd, if it was my application i have done all this on register page. but yeah company requirements you just have 1 option i will do it and you have to do it in their way not your way and that's how things work in software houses. Thank you guys Happy Coding.

Comment: @HassamAli its not odd because of some company requirements .. its odd because it CANT work at all what you have.